# Is it possible to compare different pictures of an object on different backgrounds to manage inventory?

Tags: cloud, inventory

I work for a small company that creates props for films and we have multiple locations. Props vary a lot, like vases, fruits, and swords.
The way they manage the inventory right now is by taking pictures of every item that goes out, so the client has to check the items to the pictures when they are returning and making sure the right items are going to the right location.

The process is time-consuming for both us and the client, so I am trying to figure an easier way of doing it.

What I have in mind is to use a camera to take a picture of an item and the system would show the items that are the closest to the picture, and the user would select the one he/she thinks looks the closest.

Is there a cloud a.i provider that would calculate for me?
How hard would be to create a calculation like that?

If anyone would have a better solution I am opened to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook, try DeepMask, SharpMask and MultiPath rather than cloud. You can get these from GitHub.

For cloud options- you could check AWS Rekognition, Google or Cognitive computer vision (you can upload sample and see if that can identify closely, with API you can give feedback to make it learn).